# Sorting a PHP array by a predefined order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
$categories = array(1,19,4,33,10,7,12);
```

And this array:

```
$order = array(33,12,50,19,4,1,100,18,9,2,7);
```

What I want is for `$categories` to be sorted in the way that is `prefined` in `$order`. So the result I need would be:

```
$categories_sorted = array(33,12,19,4,1,7,10);
```

As you may have noticed, `10` is not in `$order`. This is because the `$order` array never has all categories in it, only the most important ones. The `$categories_sorted` array should always contain all values from `$categories`, even if they are not in `$sorted`.

Comment: Would be easiest with [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect) and just appending [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff).

Comment: This is a duplicate of a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294932/php-sorting-an-array-by-predefined-order if I'm correct

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this achieve your challenge:

```
$categories = array(1, 19, 4, 33, 10, 7, 12);
$order = array(33, 12, 50, 19, 4, 1, 100, 18, 9, 2, 7);
$categories_sorted = array();

// first: sort what is in $categories based on $order

foreach($order as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $categories)) $categories_sorted[] = $value;
}

// then add what is in $categories but bot in $order

foreach($categories as $key => $value) {
    if(!in_array($value, $order)) $categories_sorted[] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function of php as

```
$categories = array(1, 19, 4, 33, 10, 7, 12);
$order = array(33, 12, 50, 19, 4, 1, 100, 18, 9, 2, 7);

uasort($categories, function($a, $b)use(&$order) {
    foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
        if ($a == $value) {
            return 0;
            break;
        }
        if ($b == $value) {
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }
});

print_r($categories);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/382852)

Comment: Did you get your answer